# Double underscore in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

What does the double underscores in these lines of PHP code mean?

```
$WPLD_Trans['Yes'] = __('Yes', $WPLD_Domain);
$WPLD_Trans['No'] = __('No', $WPLD_Domain);
```

Comment: Given [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php/1777147#1777147), related: *[Why double underscore (__) in PHP function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348663/why-double-underscore-in-php)*

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It looks like you're using WordPress - `wp-includes/l10n.php` defines __ as a function that translates a string (similar to [`gettext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) and its alias, `_`, but with an optional parameter for explicitly specifying a domain).

Comment: Hideous, but very convenient. As a sidenote, php.net says that all functions starting with __ (double underscore) are reserved. It sounds like they don't like the fact that WordPress and others are poaching on their magic method territory. http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Based on this, it sounds like I can get rid of this if no translation is required.  Is this correct?  E.g., $WPLD_Trans['Yes'] = 'Yes';

Answer (score 42):

Strictly speaking, it means nothing in PHP as it is not a pre-defined function. However, in many frameworks, like CakePHP, and other libraries the double underscore is a function used for translating strings based on the user's language/locale preference.

Comment: No idea. Confusingly though, the CakePHP version of __ behaves completely differently to the one in Wordpress (CakePHP, by default, echoes the string unless the second parameter is false). I'll bet *that* never tripped anybody up before...

Answer (score 9):

WordPress documents its *__()* function, and part of the localisation technology on *[Working with WordPress Core – Translate WordPress](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/translating/working-with-core/#localization-technology)*.

It is difficult to find documentation because __(), __('') or __("") is not very searchable. Double underscore and parentheses (round brackets) are some keywords to use.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned it is generally used for translating text between languages but really it is used in the same context as any function call.

```
testfunction();
```

is no different then

```
__();
```

Comment: Actually, testfunction() is very different, because it has a sane name. __ is a completely stupid thing to name a function.

Answer (score 2):

A similar or third-party [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) based implementation is [gettext()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php):

> Note: You may use the underscore character '_' as an alias to this function.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: From [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047766/php-what-are-these-underscores/10047789#10047789) to another question: *"A single underscore is an alias to gettext()."*