# Using underscore before public function names

Tags: php, function

I was just reading some code and I came across a function named `__toString`. Here is the function prototype:

```
public function __construct($par)
```

What is the reason the coder chose *__construct* and *not construct* as the function name?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663350/whats-the-deal-with-a-leading-underscore-in-php-class-methods) which says that private and protected functions can start with an underscore, but it is a public function. Why has the coder chosen to use underscore in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why double underscore (__) in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348663/why-double-underscore-in-php), see also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: "PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical. It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality."

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Why double underscore (\_\_) in PHP function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348663/why-double-underscore-in-php-function-names)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*__construct* and *__toString* are all magic functions that start with a double _.

And all private functions start with a single _ that is not standard, but developers prefer this way to identify public and private methods...

And ***all magic function are not public.***

Comment: Magic functions in what context? In PHP? Or a *convention* in particular frameworks like [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) or [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel)?

Comment: WordPress uses *naked* double underscores ("__"): *[Double underscore in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php/1777147#1777147)*