# What does the __() function do in FuelPHP?

Tags: php, fuelphp

Consider:

```
public static function get_publish_flag_values()
{
    return array(
        self::PUBLISH_FLAG_ON => __('model.item.publish_flag_values.on'),
        self::PUBLISH_FLAG_OFF => __('model.item.publish_flag_values.off')
    );
}
```

In FuelPHP, where can I find the use of `_('mode.item.product_code')`?

Comment: It's a function name. Terribly counter intuitive function name.

Comment: Not sure about fuelphp, but it [looks like a translation function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php).

Comment: Related (perhaps even a duplicate - the answers talk about some other frameworks, like [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) and [CakePHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP), but they could just as well have mentioned [FuelPHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FuelPHP)): *[Double underscore in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in `fuel/app/lang`, and if you use modules, it is in `fuel/app/modules/lang`.
It returns an array.

Comment: And also, to use you need to add one  line :`\Lang::load('your file, true);`

Answer (score 0):

`__()` is simply an alias for `Lang::get`. [See the *Lang* class documentation](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/lang.html#/function___).

It's used as often people prefer the shorter syntax.