# What is a double underline for in Twig or in Bolt?

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

I was just going through one of the Twig files in the Bolt default theme template, and I came across the following line of code:

```
{{ __("Unfortunately, no content could be found. Try another page, or go to the <a href=\"%paths_root%\">homepage</a>.", {'%paths_root%': paths.root} ) }}
```

Now I thought the way you echo something in Twig is as follows:

```
{{ 'hello there' }}
```

I googled double underline and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1777147/4381665), but I’m not sure that's the answer to my question.

So what exactly is the double underline in Twig or Bolt?

Answer (score 3):

In the current stable Bolt version, `__()` is a Twig function to call our translation layer that sits on top of Symfony's.

The second parameter in that function is the value in the string that is variable, and the value you want inserted in its place for that specific translation string, at that point.

Comment: yes i understand the 2nd part of your answer. but WHY EXACTLY is this function needed ? i am still not getting it .

Comment: Needed, it isn't… :-)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if I understand this correctly, but in the [Symfony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) framework for translations of strings you should use the translator service.

Then you could use the `trans` and `transchoice` Twig tags.

Please see Symfony documentation for more details:
[Symfony translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html)

Comment: Please emphasis !