# Double underscore in cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp

I thought double underscore always meant private function but what does it mean in cakephp 2.0 in such examples as this
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

For example

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
```

Comment: Cake isn't the only framework/platform to use `__()` as a translate/locale function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php/1777141#1777141

Comment: Voted down for lack of research.

Comment: I'm just starting with Cake and didn't realize the double-underscore was a locale thing.  Googling "PHP double underscore" talks about magic functions or something, but searching "cakephp double underscore" leads me to your question and Mike B's answer.  Thanks for asking this question and ignoring luchomilina.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The double underscore function in CakePHP handles localization.  It's used when you want to translate your application by providing a string translation dictionary.

[Cake PHP Book: Global Constants & Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#__)

See also [Internationalization and Localization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)