# What are these underscores in PHP?

Tags: php, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Double underscore in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php)

In a PHP application that I am inheriting, there exist these code snippets which I have trouble comprehending:

```
$foo = bar(array(
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
));
```

And another example:

```
$some_text = sprintf( '<span>' . __( 'Displaying %s&#8211;%s of %s' ) . '</span>%s',
    number_format_i18n( ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page + 1 ),
    number_format_i18n( min( $current_page * $per_page, $total ) ),
    number_format_i18n( $total ),
    $page_links
);
```

What are those double underscores? I tried looking for a method whose name is just a double underscore but found none. What might that be, then?

Answer (score 4):

A single underscore is an alias to [gettext()](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php). I would assume a double underscore would be a function used for a similar purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like WordPress's localization mechanism: *[Translator’s Handbook – Translate WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology)*

(A decent IDE, such as [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm) or [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), can lead you straight to a function declaration.)