# Double Underscore in PHP, Wordpress, phpMyAdmin, C, i18n, L10n etc?

Tags: php, c++, c, localization, internationalization

To quote [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php) that ended me here.

*What does the double underscores in these lines of PHP code mean?*

```
$WPLD_Trans['Yes']=__('Yes',$WPLD_Domain);
$WPLD_Trans['No']=__('No',$WPLD_Domain);
```

and related question about the usage of `__()`, `_()` etc. in Wordpress etc.

Started as an answer to the one mentioned above, and other related. But post as own question (with answer) as it became a bit more detailed.

Please feel free to edit and improve – or enter better Answer / Question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The usage of `__(…)`

Double underscore is used by various implementations. Wordpress (WP) is mentioned, phpMyAdmin (PMA) is another, and so on.

It reflects on the [native PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) `gettext()`, which in PHP has an alias as a single [underscore](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php#refsect1-function.gettext-notes): `_()`. This is not unique to PHP. [Gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) is natively a long-standing GNU project for writing multilingual programs on Unix like systems. We find the `_()` alias in various programming languages.

#### Reflection on the subject

In ones humble/honest opinion, one could say, `_()` as native and  `__()` as custom implementations of `gettext`, or other locale specific uses, is the only *valid* ones - as it is a well established convention. On the other hand it is not *good*, but even so concise. E.g. in ANSI-C standard double underscore `__` is reserved for the compiler's internal use; and as PHP is as closely related to C as it is, they have reserved it, and in general it is not the best thing to mix up even across languages (IMHO), it is on the border/thin ice/etc.

(*One issue here is the choice of [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) to use `_` as their foundation on something that has nothing to do with language support.*) Mix it in with prototype.js's `$` and `$$` and there is might some understanding why someone scratches their head when seeing `__()` – especially taking into account how close PHP and JS are in implementation of a working system.

---

### Locale support

On this step I make some notes on is the usage: **Locale support** with weight on `i18n` and `L10n`.

It is often used, as with [WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers), [2](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext), [3](http://blog-en.icanlocalize.com/installing-wordpress-for-multiple-language-blogs/how-to-localize-wordpress-themes-and-plugins-with-gettext/) and (the [well documented](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/translate.php)) [PMA](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Gettext_for_developers), by giving language support.
E.g.:

`__('Error');` would yield `Feil` in Norwegian or `Fehler` in German. But, one important thing to take note of here is that, in the same realm, we have more then direct translation, but also other quirks one find in differing locales/cultures/languages.

E.g. (to specify):

Some languages uses comma – `,` – as fractional separator, others use dot – `.` – for the same purpose. Other typical *locale* variations is centimetre vs inches, date format, 12 vs 24 hour clock, currency etc.  So:

```
       NUMBER    LEN        TIME
LANG1: 3,133.44  2.00 inch   5:00 PM
LANG2: 3.133,44  5,08 cm    17:00
```

Next layer of code you unveil would probably have some reference to the rather cryptic conventions like `i18n` or `l10n` in variable names, functions and file-names.

Once you know what they mean they are quite handy, tho definitions can be somewhat blurry. In general we have:

```
i18n: Internationalization
l10n: Localization (Often L10n)
g11n: Globalization (Used by e.g. IBM and Sun Microsystems)
l12y: Localizability (Microsoft)
m17n: Multilingualization (Continuum between internationalization and localization)
...   And so on.
```

*aich, my head hurts.*

The number refers to number of letters in the words between first and last letter. The letter before and after – is the first and last letter in the word. Phew. So:

```
       i18n                 l10n
internationalization    localization
 |                |      |        |
 +-- 18 letters --+      +-- 10 --+

i       18         n    l    10    n
```

(We also have more powerful *[numeronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym)* that does not follow this convention like `G8` (Group of Eight) -, but then we're outside the realm of programming - or are we?).

Then to the definitions:

[W3C](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n) has a rather sane definition of *Internationalization* (i18n), and *Localization* (l10n).

- Internationalization, (i18n), is the design and development of a product, application or document content that **enables** easy localization for target audiences that vary in culture, region, or language.
- Localization, (l10n), refers to the **adaptation** of a product, application or document content to meet the language, cultural and other requirements of a specific target market (a locale).

The short, and concise, version from [debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch08.en.html) on the subject is:

- Internationalization (I18N): To make a software potentially handle multiple locales.
- Localization (L10N): To make a software handle an specific locale.

### The use of *domains*

Frequently, when looking at code, reading about, etc. localization one come across the usage of *domain*. A more *search engine friendly*-name would perhaps be `Translation Domain`.

(*Here I'm a bit on thin ice.*).

In short one could define this as *context*. As a base you have a locale. E.g. Scotland. But you can further define a domain as part of a theme, profession etc. E.g. would *Java* in programming be rather different from a coffee shop. Or *cow* on a degenerated site about women vs. farming.

A page giving some clue is repoze.org with:

- [Translation Domain](http://docs.repoze.org/bfg/1.3/glossary.html#term-translation-domain)
- [Translation Directory](http://docs.repoze.org/bfg/1.3/glossary.html#term-translation-directory)

A translation directory would typically be:

```
/path/to/your/translation_root/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/
/path/to/your/translation_root/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/
/path/to/your/translation_root/nn_NO/LC_MESSAGES/
…
```

### Files used with GetText

If you take a look at e.g. PMA you will find a directory called `locale`. It contains various directories for various languages. The files are with `.mo` extension. This is  GetText specific files. One typically start with PO, Portable Object, files which are plain text files. These are indexed and *compiled* to MO, Machine Object, files which are indexed for optimization. More about this [here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Gettext_for_developers) (Same as the *PMA*-link above).

---