# What does "_" mean in gcc?

Tags: gcc

In some gcc code I came across the following construct. 
   fatal (_("%s: cannot find section %s"), file_name, section_name);
I have never seen "_" in this context.
It is some sort of construct to create an entity from the character array, very probably a compiler extension.

Can someone tell me what it is?

Comment: Can you show some more context? `_` is just an identifier character (like a letter, for example).  Is there a `#define` someplace?

Comment: it is probably a macro aliasing a long procedure name that enables string localization.

Comment: You might also find this useful to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270101/double-underscore-in-php-wordpress-phpmyadmin-c-i18n-l10n-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually a macro associated with the [GNU gettext project](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), used for internationalization.  The idea is the passed string is a key in a lookup table.  There is one such table for each supported language, with the current one decided by handful of environmental factors.

The value found in the table should be a translation of the key, into the target language.

Since looking up such translated strings is a common activity in i18n code, `_` is introduced as a convenient, short name for the lookup function.