# Putting two conditional results in a table

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, html-table

I am trying to put two conditionals if result statements in a table, but I am not able to get results.

So if the form input is empty then the result is not displayed.

To save space, I would like to place results in a table with two or three columns.

```php
if(! empty($lect))
   $result .= '<p>' . __('<table class="custom-data"><span id="si" >Name:</span> ') . '<span id="si1" >' . $lect . '</span></table></p>';

if(! empty($lect1))
   $result .= '<p>'. __('<table class="custom-data"><span id="si">Product :</span> ') . '<br><span id="si1" >' . $lect1 . '</span></table></p>';
```

Present output:

[image: Present Output]

Expected output:

[image: Desired Output in two columns]

Comment: result in table as picture attached

Comment: Can you post the code in which sets `$select` and `$select1`

Comment: sorry edited it is lect lect1 which needs to be displayed in table with two columns...kindly overlook my english poor

Comment: Then please post where `$lect` and `$lect1` get set. Clearly they are not getting set or they are being set as null or 0

Comment: @WillParky93 those codes are tested and works but i need them to be in table a bit off css may be

Comment: This question is unclear to me then. Could you post what you are currently getting vs expect result

Comment: You are putting it into separate tables instead of in one with 2 columns.

Comment: Mate you are putting the whole structure in wrong way.

Comment: (The double underscores are [a WordPress thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php/1777147#1777147)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below to separate into separate columns:

```php
$result .= '<table class="custom-data"><tr>';
if( ! empty( $lect ) )
   $result .= '<td><p>' . __('<span id="si" >Name:</span> ') . '<span id="si1" >' . $lect . '</span></p></td>';
if( ! empty( $lect1 ) )
   $result .= '<td><p>' . __('<span id="si">Product :</span> ') . '<br><span id="si1" >' . $lect1 . '</span></p></td>';
$result .= '</tr></table>';
```

Then I guess you are returning `$result`. This puts the result in one row and conditional columns.

Comment: I don't see a div in your code. Maybe post your whole code.

Comment: its breaking my site

Comment: You need to clarify what's breaking. Maybe post your whole code and error message.

Comment: sorry went out due to very urgent work.are you there.i can provide login credentials

Comment: email me here web-designer.ninja

Comment: somehow email got strucked somewhere.Thanks small div i waisted 2hours.thanks a lot