# Use of underscore in PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, underscores-wp

Firstly, to be clear, I'm not talking about the use of underscores as for visual separation of words in function names, etc., for example from the code below, `woocommerce_wp_text_input`.

In following a particular PHP WordPress WooCommerce related [tutorial](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/), I noticed the coder was randomly inserting underscores and multiple consecutive underscores, for example: `_text_field` and `__( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' )`.  This is either a convention that is used in demonstration code snippets or it has some PHP meaning.

```
    // Text Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'          => '_text_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
        'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder' => 'http://',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_text_field', true )
    )
);
```

Is there a convention regarding the use of an arbitrary number of underscores in coding demonstrations?  At first I suspected he was using underscores to highlight that certain values were specific to his case, but I really don't know.

Comment: Wordpress is the wrong place to look for conventions. But to answer part of your question: Some people use underscored_function_names rather than camelCasedFunctionNames. As for the __() function, that's globally used as a gettext translation shorthand. Starting a function with a single underscore used to indicate it being private or protected, but that convention has been deprecated in favour of having a decent IDE tell you it's access level.

Comment: What makes you suspect a relation between two completely distinct naming/syntax constructs? (One is a function, the other an input field name.)

Comment: It took me 2.389 seconds to Google "php underscore underscore" and the first result is [Double Underscore in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php) and the third result is [__() | Function | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/)

Comment: `__()` is a function … the meta keys starting with an underscore like `_my_meta_key` are not displayed in **custom fields** metabox area…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec please elaborate.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Too late…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any convention.

[`_()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php#refsect1-function.gettext-notes) (one underscore) is an alias of the PHP function [`gettext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php). It is used for localization.

[`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) (two underscores) is a function defined by Wordpress, also for localization. You can think at it as a more flexible version of `_()` but it is available only in WP projects.

Comment: Forgive my slowness to follow, but could you relate your answer to my examples - what is the underscore function in `'_text_field[' . $variation->ID . ']'` as opposed to `__( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' )` in the code excerpt?

Comment: `'_text_field['` is not a function call. It is just a string, it doesn't have any meaning for PHP. Read about PHP [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and the strings [concatenation operator (`.`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: If it's just an arbitrary name, why is the underscore necessary before `_text_field` at all?  Can't he just use `text_field` without the preceding underscore?  Why add the underscore before the string name?

Comment: *"why is the underscore necessary...?"* -- who says it is necessary? It is just a name the author of the tutorial have chosen for the variable. Check the `save_variation_settings_fields()` function in your tutorial. It uses the name `_text_field` to get the value of the field from `$_POST[]`.

Comment: The best place to ask about why `_text_field` is named this way is the tutorial site itself. It has a Comments section at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  I will assume the preceding underscore in `_text_field` is an arbitrary choice with no reason.  If it makes a difference in the code's outcomes, then I will probe more.  My thanks.

Comment: And why is WordPress providing a new `__()` function instead of keeping the original `_()` PHP function?

Comment: It's not an arbitrary choice. It's used to enabled Internationalization in WordPress, so that plugins and themes can be translated easily into other languages. You can read more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/